# Как программно вызвать команду "Обновить" из контекстного меню проводника?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, explorer

Подскажите, как обновить рабочий стол или содержание папки схожее с действием через контекстное меню?

Через кнопку или `form_load`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Shell32.dll")]      
private static extern int SHChangeNotify(int eventId, int flags, IntPtr item1, IntPtr item2);

    public static void Refresh()
    {         
      SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Описание функции: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify

Как вызывать: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHChangeNotify.
Необходимо вызвать событие SHCNE_UPDATEDIR. Explorer должно обновить, на счет рабочего стола не уверен.

Здесь вероятно решение с рабочим столом: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503289/how-to-refresh-reload-desktop/18134542

Comment: Можно поподробнее, что это? откуда это? как оно работает и что делает?

Comment: Не уверен, но кажется не подходит для задачи. Нужно, чтобы после изменения в реестре "Скрывать расширения для зарегистрированных типов файлов" расширения отображались. Приходится обновлять вручную, чтобы они появились...